# How do I pipe input to a Node.js program that uses readline-sync?

Tags: node.js, shell, pipe

I have a very simple Node.js program that uses [readline-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync) to accept input, then echo it to the console:

```
const readlineSync = require('readline-sync');

const input = readlineSync.prompt();
console.log(input);
```

It works fine as an interactive program; however, when I try to pipe input to it (in either Git Bash or PowerShell), I get a Node.js error:

```
PS> echo "1.2" | node .\index.js
Windows PowerShell[35552]: c:\ws\src\node_file.cc:1631: Assertion `(argc) == (5)' failed.
```

Adding a `#!/usr/bin/env node` shebang and running it as a script with `echo "1.2" | .\script.js` produces the same error.

Is there a configuration option or something that I'm missing that allows `readline-sync` to read input from a pipe? Is there something wrong with how I'm running it in the shell? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most probably the package compatibility issue with the node version that you are using. You need to check all the dependencies whether they are compatible with the node version that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

- I think your program is taking 'input' in the form of 'argument' but not from 'stdin'.
- when you use '|' , Input will be given to the program as 'stdin' not as 'argument'
- so to convert 'stdin' coming out of '|' to 'input argument' we can use 'xargs' in linux.

try following on linux/bash  to see if it works :

```
echo "1.2" | xargs .\script.js
```

- Just to give a example , we can see the functionality of 'echo' command which can take 'input' only in the form of 'arguments' but not as 'stdin' :

```
# following command does print anything :

echo boo | echo

# but when xargs is used after | , It displays the output :

echo boo | xargs echo
boo
```